# AS3 flash can't make calls to http or https webservice on a facebook app

Tags: web-services, flash, https, facebook-apps

I have an iframe facebook application with a problem i am not able to solve, because i can't understand the source of it.
On the iframe there is a flash movie (in AS3) that makes https calls to a webservice (it basically calls an https address and waits for an xml response).
It is fine on 90% of the cases, but some clients are not able to run any calls and i can't understand why.

They install the app, load the flash movie, but it seems there is something that stops the flash from calling the https address.

Can you think of any reason?
An antivirus? a strict security setup on the browser?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you use a self signed HTTPS certificate?

Comment: No, it's a RapidSSL signed certificate

Answer (score 1):

Loading XML files in Flash over an SSL Connection in Internet Explorer fails if the Pragma:no-cache or Cache-control:no-cache HTTP headers are set on the XML file.

Here is a helpful blog post about this: http://www.blog.lessrain.com/flash-loading-and-browser-cache-test-suite/